# How I can implement delegate method in the correct way?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm currently developing iOS app with Swift.
I've implemented a customised UIView which is addSubview-ed to a ViewController, and there's a delegate method in the ViewController called from a UIButton in the customised UIView.

When I implemented the delegate method as it's called directly from CustomView, I get an error which says "unrecognized selector sent to instance xxxx". I think there's a problem with memory capacity.

SampleViewController

```
class SampleViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let customView = CustomView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height))
        self.view.addSubview(customView) 
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func sampleFunc() {
        print("sampleFunc")
    }
}
```

CustomView

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectZero)

    func setup() {
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SampleViewController.sampleFunc(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(button)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        // 
    }
}
```

But on the other hand, if I implement the method in the way it's called from CustomView indirectly like below, it worked as I intended.

CustomView(Modified)

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectZero)

    func setup() {
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomView.buttonAction(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(button)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        // 略
    }

    @objc private func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(#selector(SampleViewController.sampleFunc(_:)), to: nil, from: self, forEvent: nil)
    }

}
```

The problem is I don't get why it works properly if I implement the method in the way it's called indirectly. I appreciate all the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SampleViewController.sampleFunc(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

This line means when you tap on button it should look and execute method on `self`(`CustomView`) and `self`(`CustomView`) don't provide any implementation of `sampleFunc`, in second case you have implemented method there and its working fine, . Pass `viewController` object instead of `self` in `addTarget` method.

You can pass `viewController object` as parameter in `init` method and then in setup method use that method.

Comment: Thanks, @C_X! I changed addTarget method like below and it looks working fine. Is that what you meant?

`button.addTarget(SampleViewController(), action: #selector(SampleViewController.sampleFunc(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)`

Comment: If you want that action method should be called in view controller, then you need to pass view controller object instead of self in addTargetMethod